# View source (html) code of the firmy.cz (nothing works) in PHP

Tags: php

Please advise me: how to view the source code of this URL: https://www.firmy.cz/Remesla-a-sluzby/Bezpecnostni-sluzby?_escaped_fragment_=  in PHP? I tested 7 variants. None of them works.

Some codes show a strange code (unreadable characters), see the comments in the php scripts below. Is it possible that this site is somehow security against code reading via php? For other sites, these scripts work without any problem.

The function to change ISO to UTF (iso2utf) also did not work.

None of the below works:

```
<?php
$link="https://www.firmy.cz/Remesla-a-sluzby/Bezpecnostni-sluzby?_escaped_fragment_=";

// TEST 1:
function get_dataa($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$html = get_dataa($link);
echo $html;
// return ��[�Z���]sG�&|m��n�lw...



// TEST 2:
$html = readfile($link);
echo $html;
//return ��[�Z���]sG�&|m��n�lw,���[�C��...



// TEST 3:
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($link);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
//return empty



// TEST 4:
$c = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($c);
if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
//return epmty




// TEST 5:
$html = file_get_contents($link);
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
//return epmty



// TEST 6:
$src=file($link);
print_r($src);
// return: Array ( [0] => ��[�Z���]sG�&|m��n�lw,���[�C��lK∲�ۻ�P$J��@"��......



// TEST 7:
$src=file($link);
$html="";
for($i=0; $i<5000; $i++){
$html.=iso2utf($src[$i]);
}
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
// return: ď[ÉZ˙í˝]sG&|mýnôlw,Ô÷[C¤äślKâ˛ťŰťP$JŞĐ@"šŃs9Ó .....
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump(get_dataa($link))` and post the full output in a pastebin

Comment: :-( output is: ��[�Z���]sG�&|m��n�lw,���[�C��lK∲�ۻ�P$J��@"��s9�Ws�_q#����������G旼�9YU� `e}�l�`"3�d�9���̼�������#ы���w�_1���{;��~�������t���t��ۉ���ՙ��v�=�K��N�xM������mq��w>�;�c]ǣ���i0�����ƍ�lGt�oI���ߋN�O���4>j8;Y'Y�Ǐ���c4�w���7��p��A{��4{t�޽�?:~���7Ĉf��j��y���u��aޠ1�x���Tv�(N���$Wb6~�?4b�ٓ'Ϟ��&=x������C...  And more cca 4000 chars..

Comment: full output: https://ibb.co/kjiLNH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the page is compressed, you need to use this php function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

in easy way:

```
$link="https://www.firmy.cz/Remesla-a-sluzby/Bezpecnostni-sluzby?_escaped_fragment_=";

function get_dataa($url) {
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  return gzdecode($content); 
}

echo get_dataa($link);
```

Comment: IMO Appropriate answer would be to check if the website is using gzip or not, so that the function will still work with non-gzip websites

Comment: It works! Gabriele Carbonai thank you very much, you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

```
function get_dataa($url) {
  $content=file_get_contents($url);
   $ch = curl_init($url); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
   $output = curl_exec($ch); 
   curl_close($ch);  
   if(strpos(" ".$output, "gzip")){ $content=gzdecode($content); }
  return $content; 
}
```